# Getting rid of text after a specific character when there are multiple of same characters

Tags: java, character, delimiter

Let's say I have a folder set up as such:

```
Games(Folder Name)
     /GameA.EXE
      GameB.FileExtension
      GameC.Yadda
```

I have a batch file that outputs a data file with all the game names so I have a data file that contains

```
  GameA.EXE
  GameB.FileExtension
  GameC.Yadda
```

I want to create a Java program to run the batch... import that data file (I already know how to do this) and then remove file extensions and output a text file that contains all my owned games list.

Was thinking of making each line in whole a tokenized string with a delimiter for the period and tokenizing everything after the period then excluding every other token in the output. BUT.
keep in mind that some file names may have other periods in them if they contain a game name with Dr. or Mr. etc...

Answer (score 0):

parse the string character by character and keep track of the position of the last (most recent) "." encountered, then pull the substring from 0 to that location and writing that to your output?